# Why is there a non-static variable error on my constructor?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, static, non-static

I'm having trouble getting my code to compile. I've stared at this code for hours and I have no idea what is wrong.

Here's my code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoPlE.jpg)

```
public class test{

    class University {
        private String name;
        private int enrollment;
        private boolean urban;

        public University() {
            name = "TSU";
            enrollment = 8000;
            urban = true;
        }

        public University(String name, int enrollment, boolean urban) {
            this.name = name;
            this.enrollment = enrollment;
            this.urban = urban;
        }

        public int getEnrollment() {
            return enrollment;
        }

        public void setEnrollment(int n) {
            if (n > 0) {
                n = n;
            } else {
                n = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        University tsu = new University();
        University vu = new University("Vandy", 5800, true);
        University mt = new University("MTSU", 7000, false);

        tsu.setEnrollment(8500);
        vu.setEnrollment(60000);

        System.out.println(tsu.name + "\'s enrollment is " + tsu.getEnrollment());
    }
}
```

This is the error I keep getting:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0pPS.jpg)

```
test.java:36: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
    University tsu = new University();
                     ^
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please post your code as a code snippet in your question and not as a screenshot. Same for your error stack trace.

Comment: It looks like your code is small. Please post it completely, including the imports.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12913767/11441011) should be the solution and explanation on your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code defines `University` as a non-static class (see [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for a more detailed explanation). You should instead declare `University` as follows:

```
static class University {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That caused more errors

Comment: @Chrys Which errors specifically? I copied your example and verified this change so there should not be any other errors.

Comment: @Chrys The duplicates should answer your question and help explain what the differences are between a _static nested class_ and an _inner class_. Currently your `University` class (in the question) is of the latter type.

Comment: test.java:10: error: modifier static not allowed here
        static public University() {

Comment: there are 6 others that say: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: The code you posted does not define `University` as a public class. Please post your actual code since the actual fix might be different between your example and your actual code.

Comment: @Chrys You don't put `static` in the constructor declaration—you put it in the _class_ declaration.

Comment: Kingkupps and @Slaw Thank you both! It worked when I corrected that!