# Java Classes - Why is one of these valid and one is not?

Tags: java, class, constructor, static, non-static

I'm kind of confused about how java classes work.

How come when I do this, it gives me an error that says: "Non-static variable cannot be referenced from static context":

```
public class Test {
    class Building {
        Building() {
            System.out.println("You've made a building");
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Building building1 = new Building();
    }
}
```

But when I pull the building class out of the Test class:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Building building1 = new Building();
    }
}

class Building {

    Building() {
        System.out.println("You've made a building");
    }
}
```

Now it works?

Can somebody explain why #2 works but #1 doesn't?

I would expect both to work or neither to work

Comment: Please check out Jon Skeet's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12913767/). Note also that you could just declare the nested class as static: `static class Building {` and this would work, but if it doesn't need to be nested, then don't make it nested.